# Obtaining the Max in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now.

The structure of the data I'm working with is that each quote has a web stage and each client can have multiple quotes. I need to establish which quote(s) for each client has the highest web stage (web stage is a numerical field from 1-6) and remove from the data the quotes that aren't at the max stage(two or more quotes could be at the same web stage).

I need to do it this way because there is some information held at the quote level that I need to show at the client level and if I let all the data in then my number of clients gets inflated.

Universe or query level solutions would be greatly appreciated.

The data structure and results I'm hoping to get look like this:

[Data Structure & Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P63a.jpg)

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Tom

Comment: Might help if you show an illustration of the data you have and what you want it to look like.

Comment: Thanks Joe you are right. I've edited my original post. It feels like it should be a simple answer but it might not be.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to do it, either in the universe, via a subquery in the report, or report variables.  Here's the report variable method:

Create a new report variable named `[IsMax]`, with this definition:

`=If [Web Stage] = Max([Web Stage]) In ([Client ID]) Then 1 Else 0`

Add a filter to the report, where `[IsMax]` is 1.